# Valgrind not showing line numbers

Tags: c, line, valgrind

I have read the countless questions about this, and none of the answers help.

I cannot post my code because there is too much, however I will provide my makefile line and valgrind info.

I am compiling with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall src/main.c src/filein.c src/make_game.c -g -O0 -Iinclude -o bin/rogue -lncurses`.

I run valgrind with this: `valgrind --leak-check=full /home/pi/rogue/rogue/bin/rogue assets/room.txt`

My output:

```
==2939== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2939== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2939== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2939== Command: /home/pi/rogue/rogue/bin/rogue assets/room.txt
==2939== 
==2939== 
==2939== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2939==     in use at exit: 117,855 bytes in 197 blocks
==2939==   total heap usage: 306 allocs, 109 frees, 121,129 bytes allocated
==2939== 
==2939== 900 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==2939==    at 0x4835978: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==2939== 
==2939== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2939==    definitely lost: 900 bytes in 6 blocks
==2939==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2939==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2939==    still reachable: 116,955 bytes in 191 blocks
==2939==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2939== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==2939== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==2939== 
==2939== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2939== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 19 from 6)
```

This output does not help me at all and I would really appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is not so much showing problems with *line numbers* but rather the *entire backtrace* is too short, since it only shows the `malloc()` function but not the caller.

You could try using a newer Valgrind version. Your version (3.7.0) is several years old, and there have been improvements in the meantime also for backtraces on ARM systems.

Comment: I am running this Valgrind on my pi, how can I update it? When I try to upgrade it with `apt-get`, I am told I have the newest version.

Comment: In response to above, I tried installing valgrind by installing from source and apparently my architecture is not supported. I can't use Valgrind on my Pi nor my Mac... great.